# Entity framework app.config configuration does not create a database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to use entity framework with code first method, but for some reason it does not create a database for me. I suppose the problem is in my app.config configuration file. I never used entity framework before. I have read similar posts on stackoverflow, but however I cannot solve my problem. I do not get any errors during compilation, but when I open microsoft sql server I don't see my database created.

This is my app.config file. I found this code online, but I don't know what should I write inside Database attribute.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ipadress" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <add key="port" value="14000" />
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AVLdataContext" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Blogging;Integrated Security=True;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Also here is my model class:

```
namespace TCPserver
{
    public class DataBaseModel
    {
        public static string LoadToDatabase(byte[] arr, string imei)
        {
            return ReversedBinaryReader.LoadToDatabase(arr, imei);
        }
    }

    public class AVLdataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Datas> Data { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GPSelement> GPSelement { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IOelement> IOelement { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
using (var db = new AVLdataContext())
{
    db.Data.Add(data);
    db.GPSelement.Add(data.Gps);
    db.IOelement.Add(data.Io);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm completely green at this.

Comment: do you have multiple projects inside your solution? if so try adding that part to the web.config of your web app

Comment: It does not solve my problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the `AVLdataContext` to include a constructor calls `base()` with the connection string

```
public class AVLdataContext : DbContext
{
    public AVLdataContext ()
        : base("AVLdataContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Datas> Data { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GPSelement> GPSelement { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IOelement> IOelement { get; set; }
}
```

Without this, EF has no way of knowing where the database is.

Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) as well.

Comment: Useful answer, but still same result. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your package manager Console and write folowing commands:

```html
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration initial
Update-Database
```

This will enable migrations for your db, add first migration and create db.